# $scope を別名に変更すると動作しないのはなぜですか？

Tags: javascript, angularjs

はじめまして。
AngularJSを試してみようと思い、WEB上のサンプルを見ながら
以下のようなコーディングを行い、動作を確認しました。（HTML側ソースは割愛します）

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller('myController',function($scope){
                                    $scope.msg = 'Hello';
                                }
                    );
```

controllerメソッドの第2引数「function($scope)」の部分を、「function($o)」に
変更したところこのFunction自体が実行されなくなりました。

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller('myController',function($o){
                                    $o.msg = 'Hello';
                                }
                    );
```

私としては、このFuncionを呼び出す側（＝AngularJS）からすれば引数の名前が何であっても
無関係であるという認識でいるのですが・・・。

$scopeを別名にすると動かなくなるのはなぜでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[AngularJSの依存性注入を利用するには？](http://www.buildinsider.net/web/angularjstips/0004)から引用しますが、

> AngularJSでは、引数の名前でもって依存するオブジェクト*2を表す、という決まりがあります。よって、この例であれば、引数として$scopeを指定することで、AngularJSがあらかじめ用意していた$scopeサービス（＝スコープオブジェクト）をコントローラーに引き渡しているわけです。

ということです。

下記のように配列を利用すれば、今回のように`$scope`を`$o`として使用できます。

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myController", ["$scope", function($o) {
    $o.msg = "Hello";   
}]);
```